# Tomcat 6 customized Realm

Tags: tomcat6, realm

I'm trying to write my own Realm to authenticate my users.
I have written a class extending org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase, compiled to a .jar file and put it in the /lib library.
Then I added this to server.xml:

```
<Realm className="wstest.tomcat.security.MyRealm"
             resourceName="myrealm"/>
```

Tomcat doesn't seem to "see" my new jar...
When I start Tomcat I get:

```
ERROR main org.apache.commons.digester.Digester - Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wstest.tomcat.security.MyRealm
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Answer (score 2):

Which /lib folder have you used? The one in your WebProject or the one in tomcat?
I'm a tomcat greenhorn myself but as far as I know you should place your JAR in the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

server.xml is loaded before the webapps. Therefore tomcat needs to find your Realm implementation class before it gets to load your application JAR files. Place the JAR in tomcat/lib and that should fix the problem.

You also need to be aware of one gotcha: don't log anything in the Realm constructor. The containerLog field is not set in there so you'll get a nasty NPE. loadInternal() sets the containerLog.